# How to capture Enter key press in GtkEntry

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkentry

I am trying to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key when it is pressed in a [`GtkEntry`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html).  Most of the resources I have found suggest connecting to the `activate` signal, but the [documentation for GtkEntry](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate) states (emphasis mine):

> **Applications should not connect to it**, but may emit it with
>   g_signal_emit_by_name() if they need to control activation
>   programmatically.

I am curious as to the rationale behind this and also what the generally accepted alternative is.  I know that I can connect to the `key-press-event` signal and check the key code, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm pretty aware of what the docs said, but I've always used, so far no trouble has arisen ever. If I were you I would used and find out through the testing if isn't work. Although you could check the code behind the in GtkEntry source to see if it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a keybinding signal. That means that GTK is set up so that when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the entry, the signal gets emitted. It can also be emitted programmatically if you want to *simulate* pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so there's no guarantee that the signal was actually the result of a key press.

If you want to capture a key press, then the best way is to connect to `key-press-event`.

That said, I don't see why you can't use the `activate` signal. Most keybinding signals should not be connected to, but this one seems to make sense. I think you should ask for clarification on the gtk-devel mailing list or file a bug on bugzilla.gnome.org saying that the documentation for this signal should be clarified.

Comment: Done and done.  Thanks for your response.  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=666364

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned GtkEntry documentation for the activate signal:

> Applications should not connect to it, but may emit it with
>   g_signal_emit_by_name() if they need to control activation
>   programmatically.

...has been changed to:

> While this signal is used as a keybinding signal, it is also commonly
>   used by applications to intercept activation of entries.

This happened on 2012-06-11 with commit [4a25bac0e7685000fff90a211db6ac60f6b74ab1](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=4a25bac0e7685000fff90a211db6ac60f6b74ab1). The commit message is:

> **Update docs for GtkEntry::activate**
>
> Remove the 'you shall not connect'
>   message from this signal. While it is a keybinding signal, using it
>   from applications is fine and, in fact, expected.

Answer (score 0):

now a day we are in gtk4, and a gtk4 way may be useful

simply

g_signal_connect(e, "changed", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), this);

where e is the GtkEntry